# Can you give each case statement a column alias? SQL, pl/sql

Tags: sql, plsql, case, alias

I am trying to do a query where it counts the number of prorata, complete and random results in a column and displays them in 3 seperate columns counted.

So far I am trying:

```
SELECT ot.ort_method,
CASE ot.ort_method
  WHEN 'PRORATE' THEN '1' AS 'Pro_Rata'
  WHEN 'COMPLETE' THEN '2' AS 'Complete'
  WHEN 'RANDOM' THEN '3' AS 'Random'
END
FROM orders o, order_tranches ot
WHERE o.ord_deal_code = 'EM0004357P';
```

Which doesn't work. Does anybody know how to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sample data :

```
with t1 as(
  select 'EM0004357P' ord_deal_code, 'PRORATE' ort_method from dual union all
  select 'EM0004357P' ord_deal_code, 'COMPLETE' ort_method from dual union all
  select 'EM0004357P' ord_deal_code, 'PRORATE' ort_method from dual union all
  select 'EM0004357P' ord_deal_code, 'RANDOM' ort_method from dual union all
  select 'EM0004357P' ord_deal_code, 'RANDOM' ort_method from dual
 )
```

query:

```
SELECT count(decode(o.ort_method, 'PRORATE', 1)) as prorate
     , count(decode(o.ort_method, 'COMPLETE', 1)) as complete
     , count(decode(o.ort_method, 'RANDOM', 1)) as random
FROM t1 o
WHERE o.ord_deal_code = 'EM0004357P';
```

result:

```
 Prorate  complete  random 
   2         1        2
```